# reset customrules.js in fiddler2

Tags: fiddler

Silly question but googling this yielded no results at all.

How can I reset my customer rules file in Fiddler 2? I've been messing about with it out of curiosity/ experimentation but now I want to reset the rules on it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CustomRules.js file begins thusly:

```
// INTRODUCTION
// This is the FiddlerScript Rules file, which creates some of the menu commands and
// other features of Fiddler. You can edit this file to modify or add new commands.
//
// The original version of this file is named SampleRules.js and it is in the
// \Program Files\Fiddler\ folder. When Fiddler first starts, it creates a copy named
// CustomRules.js inside your \Documents\Fiddler2\Scripts folder. 
//
```

...And then it notes:

```
// If you make a mistake in editing this file, simply delete the CustomRules.js file
// and restart Fiddler. A fresh copy of the default rules will be created from the
// original sample rules file.
```

*Incidentally, if you Google for `reset customrules.js`, these instructions can be found in the #3 result, which points to the official documentation on Fiddler2.com.*

And you can add a tools menu option to reset the script as well. Add these in customrules.js.

```
// Force a manual reload of the script file. Resets all
// RulesOption variables to their defaults.
public static ToolsAction("Reset Script")
function DoManualReload(){
    FiddlerObject.ReloadScript();
}
```

Script samples can be found [here](http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp).

Comment: Thank you Eric, great program by the way. I don't think I googled those terms exactly, and stupidly I erased the comments at the beginning when entering some comments of my own. That'll teach me!

Comment: The support that @EricLaw gives for Fiddler on StackOverflow and in the forums (and probably elsewhere) is amazing for a **Free**. I don't know how you find time to develop such a great app and support it so well! Thank you Eric